# How to create selection tabs for date and time field in Django?

Tags: python, django, datetime

Have looked through DateField, TimeField, DateTimeField related documents but I cannot seem to find what I need. I simply want to have a selection of month, day, year, hour, minute, (AM/PM) type option. I have tried using 'choice=', but do not get the nice behavior I am looking for.

** TL;DR: I simply want a way of putting in the date and time without having to type it in. I would like a nice drop down menu **

```
class Event(models.Model): 

     event_name  = models.CharField(max_length = 50)    

     date_time   = models.DateTimeField()

     date        = models.DateField()

     location    = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

     address     = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

     city        = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

     zip_code    = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

     state       = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

     description = models.TextField()



     def __unicode__(self):

            return self.event_name



class EventForm(ModelForm):

      class Meta:

         model = Event
```

This is what I currently have. I have removed the choices part and I even tried making my own model object dedicated to date and time, but that did not go well

I tried it using this ...

```
DATE_CHOICES = (('Jan', "January"),

            ('Feb', "Feburary"),

            ('Mar', 'March'),

            ('Apr','April'),

            ('May ','May'),

            ('June','June'),

            ('July','July'),

            ('Aug','August'),

            ('Sept','Septemeber'),

            ('Oct','October'),

            ('Nov','November'),

            ('Dec','December')

            )



class DateTime(models.Model):

month = models.CharField(max_length = 5, choices=DATE_CHOICES)
```

But I am not getting the correct behavior as I want.

Comment: I know I have an extra date var, but I am just editing it and just putting what ever. If stuff is out of place, it was because I was playing with it in trying to figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: You want it to store that way - separately for day, month, year etc or just want user to select using dropdown and store as `DateTimeField`?

Comment: I want the user to select using dropdown and store as DateTimeField

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in using jquery date picker or jquery datetime picker.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

On both sites there are exampels so you can see it in action :)

Comment: that does looks awesome, but is overkill for what is needed. If the user would want something more pleasing then I will consider using jquery, but for now I am just getting things to work.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to use [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1206/). Unless you're a django ninja and want to roll up your own multi widget, which is what you will need to transform a set of select inputs into one datetime value.

This widget is the closest you will get to do it, without using any js plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use [datepicker plagin](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) as **Erfin** mentioned (I recommend it too and also [datepicker for bootstrap](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)) for date and [masked input](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) for time or just simple selects. Anyway you should send a request with datetime information. What to do in django:

#### If you use datepicker plugin for date and masked input for time

Let's assume that your request is POST. Your date will be a string with format you specify in javascript. It looks like "31.01.2013". And time will be like "22:30".

```
def write_datetime(request):
    event = Event.objects.get(id=int(request.POST.get('id')))
    from datetime.datetime import strptime
    date = request.POST.get('date')
    time = request.POST.get('time')
    date_time = date + " " + time
    event.date_time = strptime(date_time, "%d.%m.%y %H:%M"
    event.save()
```

#### If you use just selects

In this case, it's simplier to make a datetime string from request parameters and repeat the preveous example.

```
def def write_datetime(request):
    year = request.POST.get('year')
    month = request.POST.get('month')
    # etc
    date_time = "%s.%s.%s %s:%s" % (day, month, year, hours, minutes)
    # etc
```

Comment: That looks great, but I am curious to know if there is anyway I could use Django's model or modelform classes to help me display them then use what you provided to read.